# Unslider breaks when multiple slides on one page

Tags: javascript, unslider

I'm using [Unslider](https://idiot.github.io/unslider/) and I have multiple sliders on a page - all with the same class of `my-slider`. The sliders work if navigating via the dots - but the next and prev buttons don't work.

My JS is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var slider = $('.my-slider').unslider({
        arrows: false
    });
    slider.on('click', function() {
        slider.unslider('next');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="my-slider">
    <ul>
        <li><img class="img-pad" src="img/cannes-bridge.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img class="img-pad" src="img/cannes-jean.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img class="img-pad" src="img/cannes-nis-1.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img class="img-pad" src="img/cannes-sam.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img class="img-pad" src="img/cannes-igor.jpg" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There's a live version [here](http://thisismichaels.work) in which you can see it working as intended on the first - but when you click on the slide to move on to the next it breaks on the second slider.

EDIT:

I found a similar issue on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131948/unslider-next-prev-issue-when-multiple-sliders-on-page) but I'm JS novice and can't seem to understand what solution applies to me.

Comment: can you add your html code?

Comment: @KalleshwarKalshetty added.

Comment: @KalleshwarKalshetty that was attempted by some other uses and talked about on the GitHub page, but it didn't work out. https://github.com/idiot/unslider/issues/108

Comment: Looks like a poorly written plugin that's the culprit.